# How do I list uninstalled but recommended packages?

Tags: apt, command-line

How do I list the packages that are recommended by my current set of installed packages, but for whatever reason weren't installed?

Comment: Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/340075/aptitude-list-all-previous-recommended-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a command-line list, From:

https://serverfault.com/questions/340075/aptitude-list-all-previous-recommended-packages

```
aptitude search '~RBrecommends:~i'
```

To complete your original question:

```
aptitude search '~RBrecommends:~i' | awk '/^p/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 6):

This can sometimes happen if a package B is installed as a recommendation when you install package A; package B's own recommends typically do not get installed.

#### 1. Listing uninstalled *Recommends* from the terminal:

- Use `aptitude`
- Click on the *Views* menu, and on *Audit Recommendations* (alternately, `Ctrl+T` to show the menu, arrow keys to go to *Views* and press `R`):

  [image]
- This shows you a list of uninstalled recommended packages, and the "parent" package recommending them.

  [image]

#### 2. Listing uninstalled Recommends *and Suggests* from Synaptic:

- If you have a desktop (or via X-forwarding), use Synaptic
- Click on *Custom Filters* in the bottom-left, and then on the *Missing Recommends* filter in the top-left sidebar:

  [image]
- Notice that unlike `aptitude`, Synaptic also shows "suggested" (or optional) packages such as `iproute-doc`

Comment: Unfortunately Aptitude doesn't quite work right in 12.04 with multiarch packages -- is there another terminal program that can provide the same thing (even in a very raw form)?